run .py file from the wsl shell
I'm trying to execute a simple hello.py file from the shell (a wsl really), but apparently it doesn't work. I used the following command to be sure to be in the directory containing the .py file:
import os
os.getcwd()

The error is always the following:

NameError: name'hello.py' is not defined.

Any suggestion?
I tried many possible solutions but no one of them worked.
For example I tried to write python3 hello.py without success. enter image description here

can you share the screenshot of cmd

also send the screenshot of file located in storage

oh yeah @mzjn is also right, it may be due to that too.

you cannot run your python file in python shell.

And so where can I run a .py file?

Ok, I think I have solved the issue quitting the python shell, and running python3 hello.py.

So basically python is already installed in WSL. if you have a hello.py in a windows folder i.e.
C:/Users/<user>/Desktop/hello.py

then you need to know wsl has different folder structure. If you want to access the file from windows its path starts from
/mnt/c/Users/<user>/Desktop/hello.py


Assuming you are in the right path, try running
python3 ./hello.py

or
python ./hello.py

I hope you find this helpful

The image description you provided currently looks like you're using python interactive shell, and trying to run main directly.
If you still want to run the file from within the Python interactive shell, what you can try to use the exec function
with open('main.py') as f:
   exec(f.read())

But, the common approach is to run the script directly from the terminal, not from the python interactive shell.
